# modifying error message of a standard command

Tags: bash

How do I modify the standard error message of a particular bash command ? I was trying to modify the standard error message of `kill` from `kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]` to `specify PID of process to kill`. I couldn't find any material online that helped me grasp how the error messages work or how to modify them.

Comment: That's... not really a great thing to try to do. Intercepting a program's stderr means you lose ordering between writes to stderr and writes to stdout; moreover, attempts to pattern-match that stderr content are going to be dependent on the user's language and locale settings, and if you aren't translating all the replacement strings, then you're losing internationalization support in the process. Is there a concrete benefit you'd get from this that justifies it?

Comment: It's more of a "remind myself what I need to do" sort of thing rather than something that's gonna be used by many people :)

Comment: Is it just for the case where `kill` is called with no arguments at all, then? In that case, maybe you just don't call `kill` at all in that case, instead of calling it and rewriting its output. `kill() { if (( $# == 0 )); then echo "specify PID of process to kill" >&2; else builtin kill "$@"; fi }`

Comment: That would actually work out well in my case :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wrapper function is the typical Right Way to modify a shell command's behavior. In this case, we can write such a wrapper that redirects `kill`'s stderr into a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) that rewrites content line-by-line:

```
kill() {
  builtin kill "$@" 2> >(
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      if [[ $line = "kill: usage: "* ]]; then
        echo "specify PID of process to kill" >&2
      else
        printf '%s\n' "$line" >&2
      fi
    done
  )
}
```

Running `builtin kill` ensures that the `kill` function calls the shell-builtin version of `kill`, instead of recursing and calling itself. (For external commands, you would use `command` instead of `builtin` to ensure that an external command is used in place of recursion).